# TagIt get value

Tags: jquery

I need get the value from tagit, how can I do that?
in afterTagAdded, I call to my controller and I save the object in a List<>, but I don't know how can I get that value.
I need send here -->data:{user:here the id}, the value(id), How can I do it?

```
$('#userNameFriend').tagit({
    fieldName: "tags[]",
    removeConfirmation: true,   
    singleField: true,
    allowSpaces: true,
    placeholderText: 'Name',

    tagSource: function ajaxCall(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getUserFriends.html",
            data: {
                term : request.term
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                response($.map(data.results.list, function(item) {

                    return{

                        label:" "+ item.name +"   "+item.surname,
                           value:item.id
                    };

                }));
            }
             //error: function(error){
            //alert("El valor no existe");
        //}
        });
    },
    afterTagAdded: function addUser (event,ui){
        //Ejecutar llamada al controller para rellenar array con los usuarios elegidos.
        //alert("HOLA"+ui.tag.value);
        $.ajax({
            url:"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/message/fillin.html",
            data:{user:here the id},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(){
                    alert("success");
                    //Append al div de viajes
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure"+data);
            }
           });
    }//Adduser

})
```

Comment: Please show HTML involved. And, do you use any backend language, like PHP or Python, etc. to generate the view?

Comment: The user id that you are trying to send in the ajax call inside the addUser function, does it refer to the logged on user or a user of a list of users that somehow you display in the webpage?

Comment: did you solved the issue? If so, please post here

Answer (score 11):

If you want to get the tag in the afterTagAdded function. You just need to access the property tagLabel of the ui object, like this: `ui.tagLabel`.

If you want to get all the tags that have been added so far. You just need to call the function assignedTags through the tagit object in your input, like this: `$('#userNameFriend').tagit('assignedTags')`; this will return an array with the values of the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I use JSP. 
The user id that I'm trying send is the user selected in that moment. That user has a id that i want to send, and a Name than I show in the input of tagIt.
This is the input:

```
 <input  id="userNameFriend"  name='userNameFriend' type="text" placeholder="Asunto"                  style="width: 700px;height: 35px"/>
```

Comment: So, does this means that you have n different input like the one you have specified above?

Comment: no, I have only one input. And in that input I have the autocomplete of tagit. And I would like get the list of tags,  fieldName: "tags[]",